# How to change the Scene Builder background image(default is Blue Grid)?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

The default background image of Scene Builder is Blue Grid as shown below.[image: Blue Grid Background of Scene Builder]

Can I change this background image or color of Scene Builder to some other color or image apart from the in built ones (i.e. Neutral Grid and Neutral Uniform)?

Answer (score 3):

To change the default colors in SceneBuilder, you probably need to [check out the source of SceneBuilder](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11290332), modify the css stylesheet in the SceneBuilder source tree and rebuild the SceneBuilder application.